# output format on windows

Tags: c++, io, precision, outputstream

I'm developing a projet in C++ where results are print on the `std::cout` like that :

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << "UNDERLYING=" << v_underlying << '\n';
std::cout << "RESULT=" << v_result << '\n';
```

which gives :

```
UNDERLYING=1.2454
RESULT=0.000054785
```

But for an unknow reason, when I launch the program of the computer of my team partner, the output is like that :

```
UNDERLYING=1.2454
RESULT=5.4785e-031
```

we are under windows 7 X64 bits so do you know if there is an option to change under Windows or the problem comes from the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::cout << std::fixed;` to specify output format

Comment: yeah I know it. But if my code is working on my windows computer, why not on another one ? maybe there are an option that we can change in windows no ?

Comment: so try `cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed)`

Comment: ok I'll ask my question with another way : Are you sure it's comming for the C++ code and not from the windows configuration or something like that ?

Comment: It could be comilator dependent. It'll be wierd if windows could format your program output, some applications apparence will be broken. How do you move this program between computers. Are you using the same exe file?

Comment: No, he recompiled the project on visual ultimate 2010 but with the same source code as me

Comment: Try to use same exec. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z328y9b3(v=vs.80).aspx) is simple example and in comments they inform that it should be compiled with specific flag. I'm not sure if it helps but I have no idea what could be wrong

Comment: we got the same result : `0.000054785` in mine and `5.4785e-031` in his computer....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20060/discussion-between-janisz-and-yumino)